# Incrementing variable in assembly for 8080?

Tags: assembly, intel-8080

I'm working on a program for Intel 8080 right now and I don't really get how the space we can reserve for variables work. Namely, let's say we do `test DB 80`. Can I later somehow decrement or increment the variable `test` for example or do I have to declare it anew?

Comment: No.  See what `LXI H,test` and `INR M` get you (been way too long ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INR M` instruction increments the byte content of the memory address pointed by HL register. So you can basically:

```
LXI H, test
INR M
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I use it for output after that? Let's assume RST 1 prints the contents of A. If I do "LXI H,test / INR M / MOV A,H / RST 1", nothing is printed though the simulator shows me the contents of A are not nulls. How do I print the variable, then?

Comment: 1) you need MOV A, M to get memory contents not H. 2) You need to increment a by 48 (or shift-left 6 bits) to get a printable characters.

Comment: Thank you. Am I limited to doing LXI H,<variable> to later work on it with INR or I can also point other registers to it, like LXI C,<variable>? If so, how do I point to the memory then if the M means the area HL are pointing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "test" is a byte, you could do something like this:

test: ds 1  :this sets aside one byte for storage of data and names it "test"

```
  lda test  ; move the value from the memory location called "test" into "a"
  inr a     ; increment A
  sta test  ; store the value from A into the memory location called "test"
```

; this code uses the A register and seven bytes of code space.  The incremented value of "test" remains in A at the end of the sequence.

Alternatively, as mentioned above:

test: ds 1
      lxi H,test  ; Load HL with the address of the memory location called "test"
      inr  m      ; increment the memory location whose address is in HL.
; this code uses four bytes of code space and registers H and L
; if you want to load A with the contents of "test", execute:
      mov a,m
; which adds another byte of code.